# OpenGL versions on Lion, Mountain Lion

Tags: macos

It looks like Lion supported OpenGL 3.2 (see https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/GLInfo_1070_Core.html)

Does anyone know what version of OpenGL Mountain Lion will support?

Answer (score 4):

After searching for weeks, and getting nowhere, and then finally posting to stackexchange a friend of mine has told me what the solution is! The OS X app store has an "[OpenGL Extensions Viewer](http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/opengl-extensions-viewer/id444052073?mt=12)" published by "Developer Tools, and it is free.

Install it and click the OpenGL tab and it shows you the versions of OpenGL and the compliancy. Right now (July 26, Mountain Lion) 3.2 is 70% supported on my Mac Mini Server with Intel HD Graphics 3000 card.

Comment: +1 That's something I never knew about.  BTW, it's strange how it says GLSL 1.5 isn't supported, yet I'm using GLSL 1.5 in my OpenGL project.

Comment: Never mind, you have to select core at the toolbar's OpenGL Profile.  OpenGL 3.2 is now 100% supported :-)

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that.. you have to select "Core" and not "Legacy", and for some reason it defaults to "Legacy".